# jvm gc log file rotate screwed up numbering

Tags: java, rotation, garbage-collection

The question, any idea why the GC log file rotate appends numbers to rotated GC log files, in totally un-ordered?

Running Oracle JVM [1.6.0+update45]. My rotated GC log file numbering is un-ordered.

Running jvm with following GC options:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/j2sdk1.6-oracle/bin/java  -Xloggc:gc.log  -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=100M....
```

The gc logs are rotated properly, but the numbers appended in the end are un-ordered. Here is the o/p of "**ls -lt**":

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 test  test  104857725 Feb  3 14:06 gc.log.3
-rw-r--r-- 1 test  test  104857776 Jan 26 03:41 gc.log.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 test  test  104857734 Jan 17 16:00 gc.log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 test  test  104857845 Jan  8 21:03 gc.log.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 test  test   79316146 Dec 30 18:13 gc.log.9
-rw-r--r-- 1 test  test  104857747 Dec 24 11:12 gc.log.8
-rw-r--r-- 1 test  test  104857671 Dec 16 04:28 gc.log.7
-rw-r--r-- 1 test  test  104857816 Dec  7 22:41 gc.log.6
-rw-r--r-- 1 test  test  104857630 Nov 29 17:24 gc.log.5
```

gc.log.3 is more recent than gc.log.2
This is confusing...any ideas what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: I'll hazard a guess, which you may or may not be able to verify by looking at the last few lines of these logs: A long GC operation starts on time T. It opens the file for writing when it starts, but does the final writing only when it finishes. The file has been rotated by this time, but the JVM is still holding that inode open until the long GC finishes. This means the last operation written on the file is probably going to have a long time in seconds.

Comment: so based on this guess, may be increasing the -XX:GCLogFileSize from 100M to say 1G; might give more ordered numbering?

Comment: I suppose that will lower the likelihood of such an occurrence, yes.

Comment: isnt this may be a bug, jvm simply should not rotate the gc log file if it is currently open to being written in to...IMHO

Comment: It's a matter of opinion. The documentation of `-XX:GCLogFileSize` says "The size of the log file at which point the log will be rotated". If they didn't rotate when the log file reaches that point, that would go against their documented behavior.